# File Mime Type Detection

Tags: file-upload, mime-types, apache-tika, magic-numbers

There is a necessity to identify the mime type of the file. The file is uploaded through the browser and is read by the server in chunks asynchronously. Is it possible to detect file mime type using Apache Tika with few initial chunks rather than having whole file data?

Is there any other tool to detect mime type from the first few chunks?

Comment: How accurate do you need your detection to be, especially for container-based formats?

Comment: As accurate as possible

Comment: For fully accurate detection, you need the whole file